# How can I make the state update sooner than my axios command?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have this problem where my state won't update soon enough (probably because of the filter method I'm running, which I can't avoid, as I'm using it to prevent empty values from going forward to my server) which ends up sending a post request with bad (old) data.
this is my code:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempInputFields = [...inputFields];
    tempInputFields = tempInputFields.filter(value => value['seller'] || 
    value['item'])
    setInputFields(tempInputFields)
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001', {
      inputFields //sending tempInputFields will send the pre-filter data too.
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(tempInputFields) //Down here I'm getting the correct, post-filter value
  };
```

I read that I can use useEffect for a solution, but I'm not sure how to implement it inside a method (after the user clicks the submit button)
Will appreciate any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loading) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001', {
      inputFields
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}, [inputFields])
```